# How to reduce the header font size of a ngx datatable

Tags: angular, material-design, ngx-datatable

I want to reduce the header font size of an ngx-datatable without affecting the other ngx-datatable in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Override default css

HTML:

```html
<div class="custom-datatable">
    <ngx-datatable></ngx-datatable>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.custom-datatable ngx-datatable.material .datatable-header .datatable-header-cell {
    font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks, if I put this code in material.css it's affecting all the ngx-datatable in the project. I want to make the change only to a particular ngx-datatable alone in the project.

if I put in component.css it has no effect.